# Maven assembly for .zip the project with only .jar and configuration files

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to use the assembly maven plugin to .zip my project with my project .jars and some configuration files.

I want the JAR from modules `admin` `batch_base_to_base` `batch_engine` `batch_generic` and some files into `misc`

My issue is that my assembly does not take my configuration files and it does take all my jars including dependencies jars. Below my project structure and my  POM & assembly descriptor.

Here is my project structure :

[image: Project structure]

assembly-dr3.xml :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>


  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <includes>
        <include>com.mycompany.dr3:batch_engine</include>
        <!-- for test but it still includes below modules
        <include>com.mycompany.dr3:admin</include>
        <include>com.mycompany.dr3:batch_generic</include>
        <include>com.mycompany.dr3:batch_base_to_base</include>
        -->
      </includes>
      <sources>
          <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/misc</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>configuration.json</include>
                <include>environment_placeholders.json</include>
              </includes>
            </fileSet>
          </fileSets>
      </sources>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>modules/maven-assembly-plugin</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.dr3</groupId>
        <artifactId>dr3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>dr3-package</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptor>assembly-dr3.xml</descriptor>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems when I want to only ZIP a subset of folders. My solution was to use direcctly the `maven-antrun-plugin` to do exactly what you want. Something like:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>install</phase>
           <configuration>
             <target>
           <!-- delete previous old tmp folder -->
           <delete dir="${temporal-folder}" failonerror="false" includeemptydirs="true" />
           <!-- create tmp folder -->
           <mkdir dir="${temporal-folder}" />
           <!-- copy some stuff -->
           <copy todir="${temporal-folder}/somestuff/" overwrite="true">
              <fileset dir="./folder-i-want-to-copy" includes="**/*" />
           </copy>
           <!-- copy more stuff -->
           <copy todir="${temporal-folder}/otherstuff/" overwrite="true">
              <fileset dir="./other-source" includes="**/*" />
           </copy>
           <!-- create the final file -->
           <zip basedir="${temporal-folder}/" destfile="../${destination-file}-${project.version}.zip" />
        </target>
     </configuration>
     <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
     </goals>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

I usually put this plugin in a maven profile to launch it only when needed.

Comment: Ok but there is no way to do it with maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: I have discarded this plugin when I want more flexibility. But I cannot assure you at this moment that cannot be done with the `maven-assembly-plugin`.